# HTML DOM createElement()

Tags: javascript, createelement

I have code is below :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
       var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
       var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
       btn.appendChild(t);
       document.body.appendChild(btn);
   }
</script>
```

When I Click button **"Try it"** it will created button **"Click me"**, after that I click button **"Click me"** it will do some function. How can I do that.

Comment: `btn.onclick=function() { alert('something') }`

Comment: I searched for button createelement function for the duplicate. You could have searched too

Comment: It's easy, why don't I think about that?, thanks